# Writing xlsx file with PhpSpreadsheet deletes all the textboxes

Tags: php, excel, textbox, phpspreadsheet

I'm creating a system that reads/writes a spreadsheet using PhpSpreadsheet. Does this library support the  use of textboxes? When I tried all the textboxes were deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PhpSpreadsheet doesn't support any form elements; and features of Excel that aren't supported simply aren't loaded when the file is loaded, so don't exist in the spreadsheet object when it is saved

Comment: Is this really true ? When I load an excel spreadsheet with text boxes they are still there after editing the file with PhpSpreadsheet. I can't manipulate them though which I really would like ti be able to