# Text box in phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

How coul i Make a text Box like below image ? i want to have that `77,25` inside a text box.

[image]

i used syntax

```
        $richText->createText('plain text');
        $payable = $richText->createTextRun('rich text');
        $payable->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $sheet->getCell('A1')->setValue($richText);
```

But none off this  syntax made a textbox-like in excel output.

Is it possible to make textbox using phpsreadsheet library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for Textboxes see answer from [mark-baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)

[Stackoverflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833862/writing-xlsx-file-with-phpspreadsheet-deletes-all-the-textboxes)

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround. Link your textbox to a hidden cell. You can then update this cell and the value will show in your textbox.